# Heroku and Selenium webdriver not working together

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, webdriver, hosting

I have a flask app that i am trying to host on heroku. i am using selenium to grab data from a website. locally, it worked perfect, but now I am trying to deploy it using heroku, and having major problems. before all i did was point to the path of the webdriver on my local machine. now, I am using these 2 buildpacks - https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver , and https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome . I have no clue how to get it to work, but here is some code that i have found for another version (it doesnt work) -

```
chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ['GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN']
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        chrome_options.add_argument('-- headless')
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= os.environ['CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options'])
```

I have no idea if this is correct or even close to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

# You will need to specify the binary location for Heroku 
option.binary_location = os.getenv('GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN')

option.add_argument("--headless")
option.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
option.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.getenv('CHROME_EXECUTABLE_PATH'), options=option)
```

1. Add two buildpacks:

   - https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
   - https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
2. Add Config Vars:

   - GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN=/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome
   - CHROME_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

I've posted an answer with chromedriver usage on heroku [>> here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54181339/how-do-i-install-chromedriver-in-a-specific-directory-app-assets-chromedriver/56648980#56648980)

Not sure if even after getting chrome buildpack to work, you'll be successfully able to scrape the data. Instead use firefox buildpack. I would suggest this [buildpack](https://pyronlaboratory.github.io/heroku-integrated-firefox-geckodriver/)

Type in `heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/pyronlaboratory/heroku-integrated-firefox-geckodriver` to add in your heroku slug and get started with firefox and geckodriver in your application code.