# How do I install chromedriver in a specific directory (/app/assets/chromedriver) on Heroku?

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

**Problem**

I have been playing around with a Python script using Selenium, which works fine locally (as I have ChromeDriver installed in the correct directory, which is `assets/chromedriver`), but it does not work on Heroku. A summary of the error message I get is this:

```
'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
No such file or directory: '/app/assets/chromedriver': '/app/assets/chromedriver'
ensure chromedriver is installed at /app/assets/chromedriver
```

**Steps Taken**

When deploying to Heroku, I have installed the following Buildpacks on my app:

1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
3. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome

(Note: a lot of the answers on StackOverflow talk about the [heroku-xvfb-google-chrome buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-xvfb-google-chrome) instead, but I don't want to use that because it relies on Cedar-14, which is being deprecated in April this year.)

I've attempted to set `$GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN` and `$GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM` as config variables pointing to the `app/assets/chromedriver` directory, but this hasn't worked. Does anyone have any idea of how to get chromedriver installed in a specific directory (in this case, `app/assets/chromedriver`) on Heroku?

I've been struggling with this for days now, and would really appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: install it any directory you want, then specify the directory when you initialize your ChromeDriver

Answer (score 0):

Set the following path using `heroku congfig:set` command

`heroku config:set CHROMEDRIVER_PATH=/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver` and
`heroku config:set GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN=/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome`

Verify the paths using `heroku config` command

You can use this snippet to configure your definition

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def load_chrome_driver(proxy):

      options = Options()

      options.binary_location = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN')

      options.add_argument('--headless')
      options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
      options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
      options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
      options.add_argument('--proxy-server='+proxy)

      return webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=str(os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH')), chrome_options=options)
```

I'm using proxies, but you can probably avoid that.